# SVG foreignObject not working properly on Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg

I have a problem with SVG's foreignObjects elements on Safari. I am working with SVG elements and what I am using d3.js library.

What I did is to append on canvas a foreignObject element because differently from rect or other SVG elements didn't allow to put html elements inside. Now, after some days of development I noticed that it seems that Safari doesn't allow to put html elements inside a foreignObject. Better, it allows to do and all seems to work according to the inspector, but the  I put inside the foreignObject has a background set.

The result is that I can correctly drag the foreignObject and the div inside inside the canvas but differently from Chrome or Firefox, the div's background stay on the canvas top left corner not following the div.

Here below I paste the portion of the style and foreign object code I append to the canvas

**SVG**

```
<foreignObject transform="translate(304,215)rotate(-174.86597769360367)" height="180" width="40" class="dragging">
<div class="new-rect" style="background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,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); left:-45px;">
</div>
</foreignObject>
```

**Style**

```
foreignObject{
    cursor:pointer;
    position:relative;
}
foreignObject div.new-rect{
    position: absolute;
    top: -8px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: auto;
    height: 180px;
    width: 130px;
}
```

[image: On Safari (mobile and desktop) background is away its div]

That's all. I think I am doing something that Safari doesn't like. But question is .. what ?

Comment: You may need to add a namespace to the HTML div, e.g.       
<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
I've also had some problems when the foreignObject's x and y aren't both set to "0"

Comment: @Ian not working for me. I solved using html elements

Answer (score 29):

Setting `position: "fixed"` on the `div` inside `foreignObject` fixed the foreignObject position for me in Safari (as well as on Chrome on iOS). It doesn't seem to scale the foreignObject according to the scaling of the SVG though

Comment: hey, any ideas about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63690664/safari-macos-foreign-object-not-positioned-properly-inside-svg

Comment: this fixed the position issue, but not the scaling

Answer (score 3):

Putting `display:contents` on the html tag inside  puts it into place as of Safari 15.4. But you won't be able to interact much with it since the wrapping div is now nuked from the DOM. Defeating the whole purpose of foreignObject. Sing with me Safari is the new IE

Answer (score 2):

I've found that you need to insert a `<body>` element to get it work in Safari, like this:

```
<foreignObject width="170" height="28">
    <body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <div>my content</div>
    </body>
</foreignObject>
```

Comment: Did not work for me while attempting to add in an input checkbox element.

Comment: I don't **think** you need the `<body>` tag but you're right to include the inline `width` and `height`.

Comment: doesnt help my scale issue

Comment: This helped my positioning issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

New solutions:

Do not use the following styles in Safari + foreignobjects:

`position`

`webkit-transform-style`

`webkit-backface-visibility`

`transition`

`transform`

`calc` (The calculation result may not conform to the expectation)

`opacity`

You can avoid style problems without using them

old:

I find @Quinn answer, Add some information,  First , you need get your SVG transform information, like is `<g class = "main-tree" transform="translate(875) scale(1.09)"></g>` . and You can use `d3.zoomTransform` to get these data, `let transform = d3.zoomTransform(d3.select("#treesvg").node());`

The following content is the same as that of @Quinn ,You need to select the root element under the `foreignObject`,Do not execute the code in other browsers

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33844282)

Comment: This was still a VERY helpful answer for me.  I think it does move towards a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding in an inline `width` and `height` for the `foreignObject`. This seems to work on Safari.

```
<foreignObject style="overflow: visible;" y="0" x="0" width="240" height="160">
    <div class="info-panel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/" >
        <div class="panel-text" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/">
    <h1>ForeignObject</h1>
    <p>For this to work in Safari try adding in a width and height inline on the foreignObject element. The background will also expand to the more text you add.</p>
            </div>
    </div>
</foreignObject>
```

**Demo**
https://codepen.io/chrisgannon/pen/2107d092ec56025bba036934d680f2bc

Answer (score 1):

A bit old, but I hope this could help:

As @do-ic suggested adding `position: fixed` to the element inside `foreignObject` solves the positioning, but not the scale.
To solve the scale I added this:

```
d3.zoom().on('zoom', event => {
    // zoom stuff...
    const isSafari = /^((?!chrome|android).)*safari/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
    if (isSafari) {
        d3.selectAll(NODE_SELECTOR).style('transform', `scale(${transform.k})`);
    }
});
```

Also the element inside `foreignObject` should have: `transform-origin: 0px 0px`

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your foreignObjects in group elements. I found that trying to style foreignObjects with transforms doesn't work well in Safari.

```
<g transform="translate(304,215)rotate(-174.86597769360367)">
    <foreignObject>
        <div> whatever in here </div>
    <foreignObject>
</g>
```

Comment: did anyone verify this?

Comment: Did you try wrapping them in <g> </g>. ?

Comment: It doesn't but there are slight hacks that make it work in all major browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`<image>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/image) in SVG instead of `<foreignObject>`. This can solve the scale and position issue easily to avoid `<foreignObject>` bug on Safari

Remember to change the src attribute to href.

Answer (score 0):

I found a weird bug with iOS Safari regarding `foreignObject`. When I set the `opacity` in CSS for the HTML content within the `foreignObject` (it was a button in my case) it would position it absolutely over the SVG. But it positioned as expected when I removed the `opacity`. Took me hours to debug this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i solved this behavior without viewbox and set a #svg height and width dimension

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had set a translate on the items:

```
transform: translate(10px, 10px);
```

which seemed to take them out of the flow on Safari. Removing that translate fixed the issue

Answer (score -1):

In my case I am having html content inside foreignObject tag, and my html text was not scaling in all the browsers of iPhone.
I fixed this text scaling issue by prefixing all the html tags by xlink as shown in the sample code below.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 900 900"
width="900" height="900">

<image xlink:href="img/chart.png" height="100%" width="100%" />

<foreignObject x="18%" y="1%" width="15%" height="20%">
    <xlink:body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <xlink:table width="100%" height="100%">
            <xlink:tr>
                <xlink:td id="PlanetH3" align="center" valign="middle">
                    <text>Your text which is to be scaled.</text>
                </xlink:td>
            </xlink:tr>
        </xlink:table>
    </xlink:body>
</foreignObject>
</svg>
```

Please note that second line is most important in above code sample, where you have to define xlink namespace and viewBox attribute on svg open tag.

Thanks.