# Safari MacOS Foreign Object not scaled properly inside svg

Tags: svg, safari, foreignobject

UPDTATE

Since Apple are $2 trillion company let's try and get them to fix this by submitting a bug report here: https://www.apple.com/feedback/safari.html

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251753724?answerId=253364840022&page=1

---

In Chrome and Firefox there are no issues but here is the issue in safari:[image]

its supposed to look like in chrome:
[image]

If I add fixed style="position: fixed" to the outer div then they position correct, but ther size is still the smaller one in safari.

I tried adding Body to the root of an object but that just made them disappear completely from Safari. Also this post mentions it:

[Safari is not respecting scaling applied to a foreignObject](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54221528/)

You can see very clearly hear that safari (new ie) does not respect the scaling

[image]

Comment: Could you please provide a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for us to test? Could it be related to [this bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=23113)?

Comment: not sure if its worth it, I think it's clear from the bug that it's a serious bug, but i will make you one

Comment: I think it should not take much time and probably would also be good for you for testing, to see where exactly the discrepancy comes from. I overcame this problem pre-converting foreign object content into an `<image>`, which works OK on Safari. Obviously, it is not much universal solution, but is an option..

Comment: check this, see how different the sizes are of the letter 2 https://codepen.io/quantuminformation/pen/yLOzLKa

Comment: image works fine, but I need html content due to the dynamic nature of the graphics

Comment: I started off with image and other native svg elements but quickly outgrew them

Comment: Although the issue I'm having on the website is that the items are scaled down

Comment: in the code pen the 2 text is waaay larger

Comment: ill deploy my real example to my staging server if that helps?

Comment: Another option I have used for elements that would be on top: create separate `div` for them and position and transform them to the place where they should be. Maybe I will summarize the approaches if I find time..

Comment: Thanks for the example, but I think this toy simple one is for testing and illustration better than the real one (if it reproduces the error)

Comment: i want to avoid using js to position stuff, as its a rabbit hole)

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54221528/safari-is-not-respecting-scaling-applied-to-a-foreignobject - its a bug, and there is no good workaround

Comment: @ccprog looks like FO is unusable atm, time to go back to basic svg. Safari the new ie

Comment: This has already been reported [as a webkit  bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=23113). Safari feedback is not the right mechanism. Note that webkit is open source so you could always fix it yourself.

Comment: I sincerely doubt I am able to fix SVG bugs that have been sitting for 10 years