# SVG Safari Problems

Tags: html, css, svg, button, safari

I have a button, which is contained within an SVG. Anyways, in Safari, the button is stuck to the top left corner.

While researching, I found an old SO post with a similar issue: [SVG foreignObject not working properly on Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51313873/svg-foreignobject-not-working-properly-on-safari)

The problem I have is that most of the answers said that the OP should just change to an image object. This is not possible, since our object contains a button and looks similar to this (I am using Blazor, therefore there is some dynamically loading stuff):

```html
<g style="transform: translate(@(SpaceElement.X)px, @(SpaceElement.Y)px); -webkit-transform: translate(@(SpaceElement.X)px, @(SpaceElement.Y)px)">
    <foreignObject x="0" y="0" width="@ToPixels(Width)" height="@ToPixels(Height)" @onclick="OnClick">
        <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <button>
                <h3>@SpaceNumber</h3>
            </button>
        </div>
    </foreignObject>
</g>
```

Anyways, the buttons are always rendered in the top left corner. Funny thing: The bounding boxes are in the correct positions and are clickable. Literally only the rendering is messed up.

Comment: you can search for (and report) webkit bugs [here](https://bugs.webkit.org/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=foreignObject)

Comment: Thanks @RobertLongson I'll do that today. Sadly, I need a workaround for this since I cannot rely on a bugfix, which might take months to be resolved.

Comment: Implement it yourself or pay someone else to do so.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me or the purpose of Stackoverflow. I do not want someone to write my code. Maybe someone had a similar issue and resolved it using XYZ.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. Safari's implementation of foreignObject is notoriously buggy with those bugs being longstanding. I suspect you'll not find a workaround. Therefore what are you left with?

Comment: Oh I see, sorry! I gonna search around for the rest of my day, otherwise I am going back to the drawing board and recreate the element using native SVG elements (rect, etc.). Thank you anyways!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @RobertLongson, I stumbled across reported [Webkit bugs](https://bugs.webkit.org/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=foreignObject). Long story short: "Safari's implementation of foreignObject is notoriously buggy". So the only solution was and currently still is: Rewriting the entire thing in default SVG objects (rect, etc.).

How does it look like in the simplified example I wrote? Like this:

```html
<g style="transform: translate(@(SpaceElement.X)px, @(SpaceElement.Y)px); -webkit-transform: translate(@(SpaceElement.X)px, @(SpaceElement.Y)px)" @onclick="OnClick">
    <rect x="0" y="0" rx="10" ry="10" width="@ToPixels(Width)" height="@ToPixels(Height)" >
    </rect>
    
    <text x="@ToPixels(Width / 2)" y="@ToPixels(Height / 2)" alignment-baseline="middle" anchor="middle">
        <tspan dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle">@SpaceNumber</tspan>
    </text>
</g>
```

The important part which is missing here is the styling, but this is not relevant in this case.